# How to make file to be visualized in Excel

Tags: excel, file, groovy

I've got a Groovy script that grabs the data I want out of a large text file.  I want to make a tab-separated datafile with this script and then use the file for an Excel visualization.  What is the best file type to create, and how do I create it in Groovy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write it out as tab separated file as you say?

Or you could use [Apache POI and HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) with a [groovy builder](http://www.technipelago.se/content/technipelago/blog/44) or something...